# Guaranteed Acceptance Seal

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

Now the current pattern for the Acceptance rate is having a percentage and a color. Green being the most acceptance rate and red or ash for the worst acceptance rates.

How about adding a seal for say 98% or above acceptance rate for a minimum of 20 questions asked. And probably a seal can be showed prefereably in the card or somewhere catchy with a custom image something similar to this.

[image]

The objective is to make it Crystal clearly visible and thus encourage people to eagerly answer for people who have high acceptance rates faster than it is right now.

Comment: This will only encourage people to accept answers they shouldn't.

Comment: ... and that is already happening *way* too often.

Comment: Given my reputation, I still can recieve 59 downvotes :P

Comment: @Bragboy you are aware that votes have a different meaning on Meta?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: The only kind of new badge for acceptance I'd be interested in seeing is one for people who give answers that get accepted above a certain percentage.

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Comment: @casperOne : Thanks for the update

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, the site already has a badge and reputation system to reward positive behaviour; we don't need an entire parallel system to reward one fairly minor achievement.

Second, this wouldn't encourage positive behaviour. People should accept answers when the answers solve their problem. It's possible and altogether likely for people to ask questions for which they receive no useful answers. Adding this would only encourage those people to accept unhelpful answers, when instead they should be editing their question, adding bounties, or just leaving the question in the system to collect a *better* answer for future readers.

So, in summary: No.

Comment: Indeed, if a user has many questions without acceptable answers then it's often an indication that the user isn't asking good questions.  As you say, they should be improving the questions.  If they're not answerable in any meaningful fashion, delete them.  Otherwise, improve them.  I like the idea of drawing the attention to making the question better as opposed to just increasing the accept rate.